# I have a PHP and MySQL form that opens to a blank page instead of showing the edit form

Tags: php, mysql

Unfortunately, my original post somehow messed up, and when I went to fix the indentation, Stackoverflow said that it was a duplicate post (of itself).

So, I deleted the post, but I can't repost it because it's still a duplicate.

So, the code in question is here, in a google document:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1KRGNtjnvpksnhVmx9jgysFSh_hqF3gMxB00_8095HSw/edit

Looking for any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have error reporting and display errors on?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm running it off of my Mac, not under MAMP or anything. I'm guessing I turn error reporting on in the Terminal?

Comment: Next time, use something like Pastebin for your code. Google Docs is not quite suited for code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error here:     `$ = $row['articletitle'];`

Check your syntax!

Also, enable error reporting.

Comment: Thanks Flukey. I've been working on this project all day so I guess my eyes decided to skip over it. Also, I'm totally a newb at this.

Comment: We all get tunnel vision, so no worries. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you have to test for ID `if(is_numeric($_POST['id']))`? Because it comes from the database, and you already define it as integer. And also this one,  `if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0)` which I think that there's something wrong with this condition,so that it never goes in.